# I have a heroku detached dataclip - need to reattach

Tags: heroku

I managed to kill my favourite dataclip by attaching it to a heroku instance that since got closed (assumably killing the related database).

Looking at it now, it tells me that it's a detached dataclip and that I should choose a new database to attach to, but there is no database selector to choose from (see attached image).

I stored a whole bunch of SQL clips in there for useful one-off purposes... and don't want to just lose the dataclip, I really want to reattach it to another db...

Any ideas on how do I can go about doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the solution is: put a support ticket in to heroku and give them the db-name you'd like it to be reattached to.

They're currently looking into the bug that made it not display a picker to me.